# LDAP Remote Login Logs

Tags: linux, logging, openldap, pam-ldap

How would I log who authenticated against my ldap system on Linux in my lab? I have a lab with several workstations, and one server running openldap. I would like to have similar functionality as with the `last` command with who, when, and where. The server and workstations all run scientific Linux.

Answer (score 1):

You need to increase the logging level in your OpenLDAP instance.  I believe the one you're looking for is 256. http://www.openldap.org/doc/admin24/slapdconf2.html#cn=config

For OLC, create a file with the following contents:

```
dn: cn=config
changetype: modify
replace: olcLogLevel
olcLogLevel: stats
```

Then:

```
ldapmodify -H ldapi:// -Y EXTERNAL -f <file>.ldif
```

You'll start seeing logins show up in /var/log/syslog  To get something in a 'last'-type format, you'll have to add some additional intelligence/logic to parse the syslog.

Edit: Changed olcLogLevel specifier from '256' to 'stats' as suggested by 84104.  Easier to understand.

Comment: Why are you advocating the use of `256` instead of the more human readable `stats`?

Comment: Does this method actually log user ids? I just tried it and it gave me output similar to https://gist.github.com/HSchmale16/c923c75ba908ce8b290ea4f74c2618a9

Comment: Yes.  In my logging it also shows BIND attempts:  `May  2 06:33:54 server slapd[60944]: conn=16101 op=0 BIND dn="cn=LDAPBind,ou=Users,dc=example,dc=com" method=128`